# PHP Losing session variables upon going back to previous page

Tags: php, session-variables

The home page on my website has a form with two fields: Make of the Car (carmake) and Car Model (carmodel). Upon submit, it takes the user to the 2nd page that displays information about the specific make and model that the user has input on the homepage.

I am using post-method to pass the variables to the 2nd page, where I start a new session with the two variables:

```
    <?php 
       session_start(); 
       $_SESSION['carmake']=$_POST['carmake'];
       $_SESSION['carmodel']=$_POST['carmodel'];
    ?>
```

This works fine. On this 2nd page, I have a link for a 3rd page that uses the same two session variables. So on the 3rd page, I start the page with the session function and the session variables are available for use. No problem so far.

There are 2 problems I am experiencing from this point onwards:

**Problem 1:** I have a button on the 3rd page that links back to the 2nd page. When I use this button to go back to the 2rd page, the 2nd page does not echo the session variables. However, if I use the browser 'back' button to go back to the 2nd page, I am asked to "confirm resubmission" which I do and then 2nd page correctly echoes the session variables.

**My question 1:** How can I design the navigation to previously visited pages without losing the session variables?

**Question 2:** Is there a way to avoid having to "confirm resubmission" (when using the browser back button) on a previously visited page that uses session variables?

(I am a newbie here and apologize in advance for the long post for what may be a very simple question.)

Comment: provide the code of your page 2 where you are getting the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Question 1 solution:

Change your code

```
<?php 
       session_start(); 
       $_SESSION['carmake']=$_POST['carmake'];
       $_SESSION['carmodel']=$_POST['carmodel'];
```

To

```
<?php 
       session_start(); 

       if(isset($_POST['carmake']))
            $_SESSION['carmake']=$_POST['carmake'];

       if(isset($_POST['carmodel']))
            $_SESSION['carmodel']=$_POST['carmodel'];
```

It will set session value only if form is submit (which is submit from Form1), so when you click back button, it will not set blank values and will keep last session value remains)

## Question 2 solution:

```
<?php 
       session_start(); 

       if(isset($_POST['carmake']))
           $_SESSION['carmake']=$_POST['carmake'];

       if(isset($_POST['carmodel']))
           $_SESSION['carmodel']=$_POST['carmodel'];

       if(isset($_POST['carmake']) || isset($_POST['carmodel'])){
            # Redirect on same page when submitting the form
            # will not ask for form submission when click back on browser page
            header("Location: page2.php")
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: The solution to the first question works perfectly. It solves both questions: From page 3, I can go back to the 2nd page with the back button (link) on the webpage or with the back button on the browser. However, the 2nd solution does not work. I have a question about it. Should I be placing it on the 2nd page or the 3rd page?

Comment: on 2nd page, actually both codes are same except the redirect code, which will redirect 2nd page when submit the code to ignore form submission from 3rd page.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: Unless you are checking to see if $_POST has values before you assign them, the sessions will get empty values.  Turn on a higher error log level and display errors and you should see a notice about an undefined variable.  Also, it works when you confirm submission because you are re-POSTing the data to the second page.

Question 1: Check that the POST variables are not empty() before assigning them.

Question 2: Not that I am aware of, you are going back to a page that your browser previously POSTed to and it wants to know if you want to again (to get the "same" results as before)

UPDATE: Also, you should post more code.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late here, but just thought to share my solution. I hope this helps someone.

## Question 1 : Solution

Store the value in session only if form is submitted.

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['carmake'])) $_SESSION['carmake'] = $_POST['carmake'];
    if(isset($_POST['carmodel'])) $_SESSION['carmodel'] = $_POST['carmodel'];

    /* Rest of the code goes here */
```

## Question 2 : Solution (easy alternative)

Cache control and Session cache limiter prevents form resubmission when using browser back button.

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 

    header("Cache-Control: no cache");
    session_cache_limiter("private_no_expire");

    /* Rest of the code goes here */
```

## ~ Full code ~

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    header("Cache-Control: no cache");
    session_cache_limiter("private_no_expire");

    if(isset($_POST['carmake'])) $_SESSION['carmake']=$_POST['carmake'];
    if(isset($_POST['carmodel'])) $_SESSION['carmodel']=$_POST['carmodel'];

    /* Rest of the code goes here */
```